# Firebase Android - startAt() and endAt() not working correctly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I search for users based on their usernames? I have looked at numerous SO posts on this matter but am still unable to achieve what I want to do.. I have tried to apply what I saw in those posts and is shown below:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
            usersRef.orderByChild("username")
                    .startAt(queryText)
                    .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff");

            usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    searchList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        Log.d("USER: ", "" + user.getUsername());

                        searchList.add(user);
                    }

                    adapter = new UserCardAdapter(getContext(), searchList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("onQueryTextChange: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

However, all users are still retrieved. I have seen the usage of startAt() and endAt() supposedly work for others on other posts but I cannot manage to get it to work for me..

This is how the user data is stored:
[User Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIRgr.png)

Comment: What `queryText` are you using? What happens if you do `.equalTo("fakeuser3")` instead of `startAt()` and `endAt()`?

Comment: queryText is text input from a "search bar". Trying the .equalsTo() returns all users again :( I'm beginning to wonder if I'm using the correct listener..

Comment: Bingo! See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost done right but you should add `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` after the database reference that already apply `orderBy()` , `startAt()`, `endAt()` like this.

```
 usersRef.orderByChild("username")
                        .startAt(queryText)
                        .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    searchList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = postSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        Log.d("USER: ", "" + user.getUsername());

                        searchList.add(user);
                    }

                    adapter = new UserCardAdapter(getContext(), searchList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("onQueryTextChange: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! Why does it make a difference if I do the userRef.orderby().startAt().endAt() and the userRef.AddListener separately?

Comment: By applying `orderBy()`, `startAt()`, `endAt()`, it doesn't change `userRef` but it return instance of `Query` object. Check Firebase document for more detail :)

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `orderBy()`, `startAt()`, and `endAt()` is correct according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries).

But the `addListener` method must be applied directly to the object returned by the chain of `orderByChild()`, `startAt()`, and `endAt()` methods, and not in a new statement on the `DatabaseReference` retrieved with `... .getReference("users")`.

If you use a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener):

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
usersRef.orderByChild("username")
        .startAt(queryText)
        .endAt(queryText+"\uf8ff");
        .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          List<User> searchList = new ArrayList<>();

          @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("USER: ", "" + user.getUsername());
            searchList.add(user);
          }

          @Override public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
          @Override public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
          @Override public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
          @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Let me try this (:

Comment: Okay I had changed the listener and typing f into the search bar does make queryText = "f" but the Log still prints out all the users in the db :( and  only 3 of the five users have a username starting with f :(

Comment: Yes, clear, the `orderByChild()` etc. didn't take any effect as pointed out in Boonya Kitpitak's answer. You applied `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` directly to the `DatabaseReference` returned by `getReference("users")`. I overlooked this at first sight.