# Firebase realtime Database query by child and paging result

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I have objects named "trips" saved in the firebase database, which can uniquely identify using seasonCode and TripCode combination.

[image: Json tree of database]
Now I want to retrieve all the trips which include a particular seasonCode (ex: trips with seasonCode="SeasonCose1"). but need to extract data set chunk wise. (let's say 10 trips at a time)

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(firebaseApp).getReference("resources").child("trips").orderByChild("seasonCode").equalTo("seasonCode1").limitToFirst(10)
```

I figured this query returns first 10 trips wich seasonCode="SeasonCode1". if I have last retrieved "Trip" object, how can I retrieve the next 10 trips with seasonCode="seasonCode1"?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution. I can get that through wildcard queries. 
[Firebase Android - startAt() and endAt() not working correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138431/firebase-android-startat-and-endat-not-working-correctly)